# Firefox screen content frozen, but I can switch tabs

Tags: firefox, 15.04

Multiple times a day, I notice that the content of Firefox is frozen on some webpage. But the app is not frozen! I can right click to open the menu, I can switch tabs (cannot see the content, but see that page header name changes).

- I am using the latest firefox.
- I am using this Flash
  [image]
- Java version on my machine is 
  [image]

Any ideas how to fix it? I guess this could be due to either Flash in Firefox or Java version in Ubuntu.

Comment: In my experience it is due to a plug-in crash. Not sure about Ubuntu FF but in Windows FF I will often get an error dialog (xxx plug-in crashed or stopped working) if I wait long enough. I imagine it is a web page coding error or plug-in incompatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I have encountered exactly this problem many times since upgrading to 15.04 and have finally found a workaround that doesn't involve killing and re-starting firefox (and loosing all my work/settings etc.)

If I restart unity then tabs start responding correctly.  I do this by clicking Alt-F2 then searching for 'unity' and running the command.

Seems like a bug in Firefox or Unity in Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: I'll give it a shot asap it happens the next time